# Mutate a self variable from Protocol

Tags: swift, protocols, self

```
protocol: MyProtocol {
    var showView: Bool { get set }
}

struct MyView: View, MyProtocol {
    var showView = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(){
            AnotherView(myProtocol: self)
            if showView {
                // code
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AnotherView: View {
    var myProtocol: MyProtocol
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(){
            Text("Text")
                .onTapGesture{
                    myProtocol.showView = true  // xcode complains on this line
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I have this code above. I want when the `Text` is tapped, the `showView` variable changes value and then do whatever I want here `if showView {}`

This is not my actual code, it's just a minimal reproduction example, and I'm forced to use `protocol` because `AnotherView` is a reusable view to be used from multiple sides, so I want to change the value of `showView` of only the current parent view

But `XCode` keeps complaining, saying:

> Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable

How can I change the value of the parent View's Protocol's property from the child view?

Comment: This is not the way SwiftUI works. In SwiftUI views you have to deal with `@State` and `@Binding` for value types or `@StateObject` and `@ObservedObject` for reference types to modify objects and to redraw the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check that your “minimal reproduction example“ produces the error you describe. Yours does not, because of syntax errors in the declaration of `MyProtocol`. The correct declaration is

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var showView: Bool { get set }
}
```

Correcting that results in the error you describe.

@vadian gives the correct answer in a comment. Mutable state in a SwiftUI view needs to be stored in some sort of [`DynamicProperty`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dynamicproperty), most commonly by using one of the property wrappers [`@State`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state), [`@Binding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding), or [`@ObservedObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/observedobject).

But it is difficult to understand how to fix your example, because in your example, you have a `MyView` that passes itself to `AnotherView` and expects the `AnotherView` to mutate the passed-in `MyView`. That is not really how SwiftUI is designed to work. In SwiftUI, mutable state needs to be more cleanly separated from views.

Perhaps this captures your intended effect:

```
struct MyViewState: MyProtocol {
    var showView = false
}

struct MyView: View {
    @State var state: any MyProtocol = MyViewState()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(){
            AnotherView(myProtocol: $state)
            
            if state.showView {
                // code
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AnotherView: View {
    @Binding var myProtocol: any MyProtocol
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("Text")
                .onTapGesture {
                    myProtocol.showView = true  // xcode complains on this line
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that, because `AnotherView` expects a `MyProtocol` existential, I had to explicitly declare `state` to be an existential (`any MyProtocol`) in `MyView`. You can learn more about existentials by watching [WWDC 2022: Embrace Swift generics](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110352/) and [WWDC 2022: Design protocol interfaces in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110353/).

It's probably better to avoid using existentials here and instead make `AnotherView` generic, like this:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @State var state = MyViewState()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(){
            AnotherView(myProtocol: $state)
            
            if state.showView {
                // code
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AnotherView<My: MyProtocol>: View {
    @Binding var myProtocol: My
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("Text")
                .onTapGesture {
                    myProtocol.showView = true  // xcode complains on this line
                }
        }
    }
}
```